# Change slug if it was repeatedly used as custom post title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

**Custom post** -> "Children"

**Add New**-> If children name already then change with title with his birthday

By default Wordpress used ***Same_Title*** and ***Same_Title-2*** in slug.

Can you suggestion me how.?

RND not given proper solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the 'wp_unique_post_slug' filter, located in wp-includes/post.php